# How do I fully purge large xarray dataset after spatial and temporal indexing? Memory Issues persist

Tags: memory, python-xarray

My initial dataset is large, consisting of 21536 (times) x 3500 (lat) x 7000 (lat)

My first step is to chunk all dimensions

Next I select only the lat/lon I need(xarray.Dataset.sel), making my dataset only 21536 x 400 x 700

And, I resample time from 2min to 1day making the xarray.dataset 31 x 400 x 700

When I go to plot the values, I get an error, saying I don't have the memory for 21536x3500x7000
BUT THIS IS NOT THE ARRAY I'm trying to plot

I've tried del data, gc.collect(), xr.dataset.close()

I've tried exporting the smaller array to a netcdf

I've tried persisting the smaller array in memory

My understanding is xarray.open_dataset lazy loads the data and keeps the file open.  I tried xarray.load_dataset and didn't have the memory.

I've tried iteratively appending value of indexed smaller array to new array and ended up with memory error

How do I purge my memory of the larger dataset and only use values of smaller dataset

Comment: Hi there - welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guides to [ask], how to create a [mre], and how to [format your code](/help/formatting). When asking a question, please include all of the code necessary for us to understand the problem. A narrative description of what you're doing isn't sufficient. And when asking about errors please be sure to include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). Thanks!

Comment: Generally, when working with dask, be sure to keep in mind dask's [lazy execution](https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html). My guess is that you haven't done any operations *until* you try to plot, save, etc. which is when you're seeing the error. All you've done is schedule the operation in dask, and then you're seeing the memory explode when you try to execute it.